# Break multiple lines in a text file into a list of lists

Tags: python

I am working with a text file ex:

```
blahblahblahblahblahblahblah
blahblahblahblahblahblahblah
start
important1a important1b
important2a important2b
end
blahblahblahblahblahblahblah
```

What I want is to get an output like

```
["'important1a', 'important1b'", "'important2a', 'important2b'"]
```

Where each important line is split into individual elements, but they are grouped together by line in one list.

I have gotten close with this:

```
import shlex

useful = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        if "start" in line:
            break
    for line in myfile:
        if "end" in line:
            break       
        useful.append(line)

data = "".join(useful)

split_data = shlex.split(data)
print split_data
```

This outputs:

```
['important1a', 'important1b', 'important2a', 'important2b']
```

There is no distinction between lines.

How can I modify this to distinguish each line? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehensions to the rescue:

```
[", ".join(map(repr, ln.split())) for ln in open("test.txt")
                                  if "important" in ln]
```

returns

```
["'important1a', 'important1b'", "'important2a', 'important2b'"]
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little, I'm not sure what the "..." represents. Thanks!

Comment: @BradConyers: the `...` is the interactive Python interpreter's continuation prompt. You don't write it yourself.

Comment: Gotcha, so when I implement this into my actual text file, I get a lot of \'"A"\' where A already has quotes in the text file. What might cause this? Also, if there are directory path, it's adds 3 extra backslashes between each level in the directory C:\\\\something.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
useful = []
for line in open('test.txt'):
    parts = line.split()
    if parts[1:]:
        useful.append("'%s'" % "', '".join(parts))

print useful
```

Comment: Thanks! This appears to recognize both lines, but I'm not sure how to make it distinguish each line by quotes.

Comment: @BradConyers: I wasn't sure if that was intended or an accident, I'll modify the code to do just that :)

Comment: @BradConyers: looking at the code though... I think the idea is wrong. Can you tell me what your goal is? Producing this output seems like a bad idea to me :)

Comment: Thanks for the update! The goal is to have just one variable that can be compared against this result. For example x=["'1a','1b'","'2a','2b'"] and y = ["'1d','1b'","'2a','2c'"], if I compare these two, then the test would fail. That's my ultimate goal. I hope this helped.

Comment: @BradConyers: you're right, I reversed the quotes, it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehensions. Your code would look like:

```
useful = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        if "start" in line:
            break
    for line in myfile:
        line = line.strip()
        if "end" in line:
            break       
        useful.append(line)

print(["'%s'" % ','.join(elem.split(' ')) for elem in useful])
```